# Using MIN function with 2 match/index functions

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, min

Used this INDEX/MATCH/MAX function to get correct output for the following table

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10000,MATCH(MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$10000=$F1)*$D$2:$D$10000,)),INDEX(($A$2:$A$10000=$F1)*$E$2:$D$10000,),0))
```

[image]

FOR 11/4/1998 OUTPUT WAS 11:30

Problem is:  When I change the formula from Col D(High) to Col E(Low) and use MIN instead of MAX I get an incorrect result:  10:00 instead of 15:00

What would be the correct formula to use to get correct time from the MIN in Col E for each date?

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>AGGREGATE()</kbd> Function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B:$B/($E:$E=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E:$E/(G2=$A:$A),1)),1)
```

---

&, [image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B:$B/($D:$D=AGGREGATE(14,6,$D:$D/(G2=$A:$A),1)),1)
```

---

**Note :** Using `Structured Reference` aka `Tables` would be better, its recommended not to use the whole range and make unnecessary iterations for the blank rows, that said convert your source data and use the following way:

[image]

---

• For Min

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,High_Low_Table[Time]/(High_Low_Table[Low]=
 AGGREGATE(15,6,High_Low_Table[Low]/(G2=High_Low_Table[Date]),1)),1)
```

---

• For Max

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,High_Low_Table[Time]/(High_Low_Table[High]=
 AGGREGATE(14,6,High_Low_Table[High]/(G2=High_Low_Table[Date]),1)),1)
```

---

Change source table name as per your suit, cell references and ranges accordingly as well.

---

Comment: When I use this formula:=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B:$B/($D:$D=AGGREGATE(14,6,$D:$D/(G2=$A:$A),1)),1) I get an output of 16:00.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For which date? @John. As you can see the screenshot that `16:00` is showing for `11/5/1998` for `High Column` for a value of `113.81` while for `11/4/1998` it will be `11:30` for a value of `113.O9`

Comment: @John also may be if you are not using `MS365` or `Excel 2021` would need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting edit mode.